# Multiple independent handlers for threads

Tags: c, multithreading, signals

I got a problem in C with multiple threads and signal handlers:

The main routine calls multiple loads. Each load has its own controller. The controllers then send signals to pause and resume to their respective loads at different times.

The code of the load looks something like this:

```
static void signal_handler(int signo) {
  /* When signal PAUSE received, get into loop until RESUME arrives */
  while (signo != SIGNAL_RESUME) {
    /* While in the loop, the main routine gets paused */
    sigwait(signalsBetweenControllerandLoad, &signo);
  }
}

int load_main() {
  signal(SIGNAL_PAUSE, signal_handler);
  signal(SIGNAL_RESUME, signal_handler);
  while(1) {
    /*calculating something */
  }
}
```

The code works when only one load is used. But when multiple loads are running, they start to interfere sometimes. If they do so, the program just freezes at execution. But sometimes the code finishes as expected. The fewer the loads, the higher the possibility that the program works as expected.

Can someone tell me why it does not work? On research I found out that a process (and thus all its child processes) can only have one signal handler active at a time. Is this true?

EDIT: I try to reformulate my main problem: How can I pause / resume the section `/*calculating something */` in `load_main()` at an arbitrary time when I cannot modify this section ("Black box", externally given function)?

Thank you very, very much!

Answer (score 1):

From [signal's man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html), it mentioned that signal is per-process attribute.  So in a multithreaded program, the signal handler is the same for all the threads.

You can try to use semaphore to replace the signal method that you are trying to use. For more detail, you can read the [POSIX semaphore man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html).  It also has example code for your reference.

Comment: @IsQb Do you have to use signal to accomplish this feature?  As I have mentioned there can only be one signal handler for a process.  So if all your thread calls the same handler, you have no way to do synchronization.

Comment: This means I cannot use the handler to pause the main routine (because while thread A waits in the handler and another thread B would try to pause / resume, it can't handle the request as the handler in A is still busy and can't be used in B), but I need to catch the running / pause state in the main routine? If so, I would adjust the `while(1)` line in the `load_main`. But this would mean I could only pause  when `/* calculating something */` finished and starts again. And I want to pause during this part.

Comment: or put differently: I want to pause / resume in the /* calculating something */ section, without changing anything within the section itself. How it is done is secondary...

Comment: Does the `/* calculating something */` part has shared data between different thread(such as A/B in your comment)?  If yes, then it is best to use mutex/semaphore to protect them.  For example, create a semaphore with 1 as count.  When A grabs the semaphore, B is blocked for some time.  Then after A has done with calculation, A releases the semaphore, then B can go do the calculation.  Is this what you want?

Comment: No, not exactly. I have controllers `C0`...`Cn` and loads `L0`...`Ln`. `L0`...`Ln` are independent of each other and do not share data. `C0`...`Cn` then should pause / resume their respective loads at arbitrary time, independent of each other. `C0`...`Cn` also do not share data.